# Objective C : Webviewcontroller is reloading after opening photo gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, photo-gallery

I am working on an `iOS` application. In my app I have a `viewController` containing `UIWebview`. I loaded a url in that web view. There is a 'Upload' button in that webpage. When we click on that button it will open the phones photo gallery and user can select a photo from gallery.

My problem is after selecting any photo from gallery the view controller is getting reloaded and again the same url is opening in the web view. So I can't upload any files.

Anybody please help me. Please.

Thanks,
AKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Probably you are loading the url in webview in viewdidAppear:
Try implementing it in viewDidLoad Method. ViewDidAppear will be called everytime another viewcontroller is dismissed

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine now. Thanks Again.

Comment: @sahilchaddha1993 How come you know AKS is loading url in viewdidAppear ?

Comment: I assumed since he mentioned that whenever he is presenting Image Picker and after dismissing it, his webview was reloading, since viewdidappear is always called after presented view controller is dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

Methods `viewDidApprear` and `viewWillAppear` called every time whenever app navigate back to the same `viewController`.

in this case use `viewDidLoad` method this will called once whenever the view controller needs to load its view hierarchy **or** you can use `GCD dispatch_once` to execute code once in a life cycle see below code.

```
 static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
```